# É possível efetuar o tratamento de exceções sem o catch?

Tags: java

Estou aprendendo sobre tratamento de exceções e me veio a dúvida se há possibilidade de usar o tratamento sem o comando `catch`.

Comment: Olá Lucas. Sua pergunta está um pouco ampla / ambígua.  Em Java é possível ter uma sequência `try {} finally {}` sem `catch` (e.g., para executar determinado comando após `try` mesmo que uma exceção ocorra no meio do caminho). O bloco `catch` porém, é o mecanismo disponibilizado pela linguagem para tratar / reagir a exceções. Há também mecanismos alternativos para tratamento de erros como retorno de códigos de erro e construções monádicas (e.g., `Try`, `Either`, `CompletableFuture`). Se você esclarecer melhor o que quer dizer com "usar o tratamento" isso talvez facilite uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

acredito que não.

A ideia por detrás das exceções é que quando você usa a palavra-chave try, você está dizendo a linguagem para fazer uma copia da pilha de execução da thread atual. Lá estão as variáveis da função atual e das funções que chamaram ela. E estas variáveis apontam para os objetos no heap.

Quando ocorre a exceção, sua pilha está em um estado diferente. A cópia realizada pelo try imediatamente anterior irá substituir a atual, fazendo a aplicação "voltar" a um estado anterior e que é seguro (ou deveria ser).

Caso não exista um catch até o método main. A própria JDK irá tratar a exceção e sair da aplicação prematuramente.

A [especificação do java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18) diz algo similar (tradução feita por mim de forma livre):

> A palavra-chave *throw* inicia uma exceção para ser lançada. O
>   resultado é a trasnferência do controle de execução que sairá de
>   múltiplos blocos ({}), construtores (de classe), inicalizadores,
>   inicializadores e chamadas de métoso até que um bloco try seja
>   encontrado que trate (catches) a exceção gerada. Se nenhum try é
>   encontrado, então a execução da thread será terminada...